# Jmeter Best Practices and Reporting

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter. so i want to know about what is jmeter best practices. can anyone explain shortly about Jmeter Best Practices?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Answer (score 2):

The main and only one "best practice" for Performance Testing and its subtypes ([load testing, stress testing, soak testing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924357.aspx)) is: **well behaved performance test must represent real application usage by real users as close as possible**, otherwise the test doesn't make sense.

So keep it in mind while designing your test plan, for example if you are testing a web application you need to keep in mind that the real user is a real person sitting in front of real computer and using a real browser. So you need to:

- Accurately mimic real user test scenario in terms of [HTTP Requests](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
- Make sure you properly configure JMeter to handle [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) (images, scripts, styles, fonts)
- Make sure you handle [Cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- Make sure to send relevant [HTTP Headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) (User-Agent, Accept-Encoding, etc.)
- Make sure JMeter is configured to represent [browser cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- Real users need some time to "think" between operations so add reasonable delays using [timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)

Once you have test ready you can [run it in command-line non-GUI](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) mode and analyze results using [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).